# Exception log interpreting issue

Tags: android

Where should I look at my app code to solve the issue that is throwing this exception?? I am not able to interprete it:

```
04-10 13:51:21.301: E/AndroidRuntime(1161): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-10 13:51:21.301: E/AndroidRuntime(1161): Process: com.solinpromex.vivegrancanaria, PID: 1161
04-10 13:51:21.301: E/AndroidRuntime(1161): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
04-10 13:51:21.301: E/AndroidRuntime(1161):     at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1123)
04-10 13:51:21.301: E/AndroidRuntime(1161):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:698)
04-10 13:51:21.301: E/AndroidRuntime(1161):     at com.solinpromex.vivegrancanaria.Ofertas_ApplicationAdapter.getView(Ofertas_ApplicationAdapter.java:49)
04-10 13:51:21.301: E/AndroidRuntime(1161):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2263)
04-10 13:51:21.301: E/AndroidRuntime(1161):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1263)
04-10 13:51:21.301: E/AndroidRuntime(1161):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1175)
04-10 13:51:21.301: E/AndroidRuntime(1161):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
04-10 13:51:21.301: E/AndroidRuntime(1161):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
04-10 13:51:21.301: E/AndroidRuntime(1161):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
04-10 13:51:21.301: E/AndroidRuntime(1161):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1052)
04-10 13:51:21.301: E/AndroidRuntime(1161):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:590)
04-10 13:51:21.301: E/AndroidRuntime(1161):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
04-10 13:51:21.301: E/AndroidRuntime(1161):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
04-10 13:51:21.301: E/AndroidRuntime(1161):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
04-10 13:51:21.301: E/AndroidRuntime(1161):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
04-10 13:51:21.301: E/AndroidRuntime(1161):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
04-10 13:51:21.301: E/AndroidRuntime(1161):     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:327)
04-10 13:51:21.301: E/AndroidRuntime(1161):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
04-10 13:51:21.301: E/AndroidRuntime(1161):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
04-10 13:51:21.301: E/AndroidRuntime(1161):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
04-10 13:51:21.301: E/AndroidRuntime(1161):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
04-10 13:51:21.301: E/AndroidRuntime(1161):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
04-10 13:51:21.301: E/AndroidRuntime(1161):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1916)
04-10 13:51:21.301: E/AndroidRuntime(1161):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1113)
04-10 13:51:21.301: E/AndroidRuntime(1161):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1295)
04-10 13:51:21.301: E/AndroidRuntime(1161):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
04-10 13:51:21.301: E/AndroidRuntime(1161):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
04-10 13:51:21.301: E/AndroidRuntime(1161):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
04-10 13:51:21.301: E/AndroidRuntime(1161):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
04-10 13:51:21.301: E/AndroidRuntime(1161):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
04-10 13:51:21.301: E/AndroidRuntime(1161):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
04-10 13:51:21.301: E/AndroidRuntime(1161):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
04-10 13:51:21.301: E/AndroidRuntime(1161):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-10 13:51:21.301: E/AndroidRuntime(1161):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-10 13:51:21.301: E/AndroidRuntime(1161):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-10 13:51:21.301: E/AndroidRuntime(1161):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-10 13:51:21.301: E/AndroidRuntime(1161):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-10 13:51:21.301: E/AndroidRuntime(1161):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-10 13:51:21.301: E/AndroidRuntime(1161):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-10 13:51:21.301: E/AndroidRuntime(1161):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-10 13:51:21.351: W/ActivityManager(380):   Force finishing activity com.solinpromex.vivegrancanaria/.Ofertas_MainActivity
```

EDITED HERE, INCLUDING MORE CODE

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Ofertas_ApplicationAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Ofertas_Application>{
    private List<Ofertas_Application> items;

    public Ofertas_ApplicationAdapter(Context context, List<Ofertas_Application> items) {
        super(context, R.layout.ofertas_app_custom_list, items);
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;

        if(v == null) {
            LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            v = li.inflate(R.layout.ofertas_app_custom_list, null);           
        }

        Ofertas_Application app = items.get(position);

        if(app != null) {
            ImageView icon = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.appIcon);
            TextView titleText = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.titleTxt);
            LinearLayout ratingCntr = (LinearLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.ratingCntr);
            TextView dlText = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.dlTxt);

            if(icon != null) {
                Resources res = getContext().getResources();
                String sIcon = "com.sj.jsondemo:drawable/" + app.getIcon();
                icon.setImageDrawable(res.getDrawable(res.getIdentifier(sIcon, null, null)));
            }

            if(titleText != null) titleText.setText(app.getTitle());

            if(dlText != null) {
                NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
                dlText.setText(nf.format(app.getTotalDl())+" dl");           
            }

            if(ratingCntr != null && ratingCntr.getChildCount() == 0) {       
                /*
                 * max rating: 5
                 */
                for(int i=1; i<=5; i++) {
                    ImageView iv = new ImageView(getContext());

                    if(i <= app.getRating()) {
                        iv.setImageDrawable(getContext().
                        getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.start_checked));
                    }
                    else {               
                        iv.setImageDrawable(getContext().
                        getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.start_unchecked));
                    }

                    ratingCntr.addView(iv);
                }
            }
        }

        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: show your MainActivity code?

Comment: ResourcesNotFoundException. Clean your project first. If no changes, check if the resource exists under proper name in R.java.

Comment: I suppose it is possible that something is mapping to 0 in R.java, but  I think it is more likely that a value from some other source is being mistakenly misused as a resource ID - we really do need to see the code of Ofertas_ApplicationAdapter.java

Comment: @ChrisStratton, I will include that code on my question.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, thank you, you have the code at the end of my question.

Comment: @Onik, thank you, I have cleaned the project but the issue is still there. I have included the code for Ofertas_ApplicationAdapter.java, this file may be responsible for the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error occurs on this line of code

```
icon.setImageDrawable(res.getDrawable(res.getIdentifier(sIcon, null, null)));
```

Because Resource.getIdentifier() is [documented](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) with the following error response:

> Returns 0 if no such resource was found. (0 is not a valid resource ID.)

and attempting to call getDrawable() with an ID of 0 is indeed your failure.

Apparently, you have no resource called by whatever name sIcon contains as result of

```
String sIcon = "com.sj.jsondemo:drawable/" + app.getIcon();
```

It might be worth simply logging sIcon between assigning it and attempting to use it, to see if the name is sensible - perhaps you are improperly constructing it.  Another possibility is that some of your cases may simply not have icons in which can you could substitute a default or a picture of a "?" or something.

Comment: is it possible that the problem could be in the path to the drawable folder? I mean at com.sj.jsondemo